# arc/curve overlay at elevation/bearing over iphone camera

Tags: ios, overlay, augmented-reality

Folks,

I am looking for pointers/directions on what should I learn/read about in order to accomplish what I need to. I am NOT looking for a whole solution/answer (unless you have that ready of course :)).

My problem is that I would like to present an overlay over a camera/video view. The overlay consists of an ARC/curve that has dots all over it. The overlay will be there but it will only show when the user tilts the device to elevation X (degrees) and bearing Y.

A couple of examples can be seen in the following two videos on youtube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRLpKZMCRHo at time 0:15 to 0:50 and
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oemvZl151eY at time 0:14 till end (0:48)

I have never used quartz/graphics/spritekit and I don't even know if these are useful to do this hence I don't know where to start…

Appreciate your assistance. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach is with quartz. Plot your arc or curve using `CGContext` draw functions into a `UIView` which you lay over the camera view. This is done easily inside `UIView`'s `drawRect:` method, since you can easily retrieve a `CGContext` of the particular `UIView`. To better explain this, here's an example:

```
//
//  PlotView.m
//  testApp
//
//  Created by Me on 10/20/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Me. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PlotView.h"

@implementation PlotView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //The CGContext for this UIView instance
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Set the draw style
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    //Add elements to draw
    CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect), CGRectGetWidth(rect)/2, M_PI_4, 3*M_PI_4, YES);
    //commit draw
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);

    //additional parts with different draw setup
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50));
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}

@end
```

You can plot everything in this single view and just adjust its position according to the device movement. Also you can hide/show the view normally (changing `alpha` or `hidden` property).
To trigger an update (when e.g. satelittes change position) call the `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` method. For optimization's sake if necessary use the `rect` parameter in the latter (and also the same parameter in the `drawRect` method) to trigger redraw only on parts of the view where it is necessary (and also draw only in this rectangle).

Regarding the curve you need to display: I'm sure you'll find a suitable `CGContextAdd...` function with the shape you need to draw, whether it's an arc, a set of straight lines or a Bezier curve.

Comment: Burax, thank you for a very detailed answer, It is a very nice introduction to what I need to be further looking at/researching. For now I'll vote up the answer and after researching/trying the stuff you mentioned during the course of the week, I'll come back and mark it as an answer. Again, Thanks a lot for the intro! Appreciate it!

Comment: burax, sorry for the late comment: I have been away for some time and couldn't fully understand/learn your proposed solution until now. I did NOT yet implement it, I have a couple of questions and would greatly appreciate it if you can take a minute to answer:

1- You say "Plot your arc or curve using CGContext draw functions into a UIView which you lay over the camera view" Will that work if the arc/view will be much larger that the screen size and set it based on the current device bearing?

Comment: 2- Satellites don't really change position (geostationary) so based on a location lat/long and bearing X degrees (also elevation), the curve with the satellite dots will always be the same. Only when the bearing X and elevation of the device change that the curve will move... (just saying)